# How to generate encryption key for use with attr_encrypted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cryptography

I'm considering using the [attr_encrypted](https://github.com/shuber/attr_encrypted) gem for field-level encryption in a Rails app. How do I generate an encryption key for use with this gem?

Update:

The documentation for [Encryptor](https://github.com/shuber/encryptor), which is the underlying encryption used by attr_encrypted, states the following (under Usage | Basic):

```
secret_key = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest('a secret key')
encrypted_value = Encryptor.encrypt('some string to encrypt', :key => secret_key)
```

I would guess that `a secret key` can be any arbitrary-length random string and the call to `hexdigest` will compute an appropriate fixed-length string from it. Is this the recommended way to do it?

Comment: I tried to answer, but have a question: who (or what kind of scenario) are you trying to keep the plaintext data secret from?

Comment: Certain fields in the database need to be encrypted at rest mainly for off-site backup purposes (where the off-site backup system does not have access to the encryption key).

Comment: In that case, I would guess the off-site system has access to the data, but not the configuration or source-code? I would probably still err towards configuration to store at least part of the key, and use the gem's ability to call a method to fetch the correct key as a way of feeding that in. But if the source code is secured independently of the backup data, hard-coding of encrypt keys per field is workable too.

Comment: That's right, Neil. As mentioned in my comment to your answer, the backups and source code will be separated from the configuration, which will contain the encryption key. Non-production deployments (for test etc.) will not have access to the production configuration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key is just a string, any string will do, you just want to keep it away from people who are not allowed to see the plaintext data. You could simply generate a key using `SecureRandom.base64`. That would make it practically unguessable by brute force, with very little effort from you.

The interesting thing here is key management. Your options with this gem appear to be:

- Hard-code the key into the application. This prevents "accidental" reading of sensitive data by e.g. a DBA or support engineer, but it is not secure from anyone who knows how the gem works, if they can access both the source code and the database.
- Reference a named method which will determine the key. This is more interesting, but beware: Putting the key into the database does not really add much security. Someone who can access the database and code can do much the same as if the value were hard-coded.

You can improve things slightly, or at least get the development team separated from the encrypted data, by having the application read at least part of the key from a location that developers (or perhaps just the majority of developers) cannot access in production. Going beyond that is harder, at least with this gem as-is, because the application will need to run with access to the encrypt/decrypt keys.

Whether or not this is good enough depends on why you are encrypting the data in the first place.

Comment: +1. Thanks, Neil. The main purpose of encryption in my case is encryption at rest of data in database backups which will be off-site and physically separate from the key. The key will also be kept separate from the code: most likely, it will be set through an environment variable which will only be set to the production key value on the production server. The key will not be embedded in the application's source code.

Comment: How long should the generated key be?

Comment: The default output from `SecureRandom.base64` should be adequate (~22 varying characters), other than that I'd probably pick say 20 characters plus, as you can afford to have something that would be awkward to type. Making it extra long doesn't really increase security for you IMO.

Comment: @RichardCook: just following up on your comment regarding key length.  In `attr_encrypted` version `3.0.0+`, the key must be at least 32 characters long (using default configs).  Some of the different encryptor algorithms actually require much longer keys...varies by encryptor.  Just mentioning this because I just added the `3.0.0` version in an app I'm working on and ran across that situation in `development`.